# Display HTML page containing DataTables in Shiny App

Tags: jquery, r, datatables, shiny

as a result of my data pre-processing for my shiny app I'm generating .Rbin and a short .html report with some info and a few tables (using DataTables). The report was always stand alone file, but now I want to include it in the shiny app. I've spent quite a while solving this problem and the only result I got is that problem is with DataTables.

This is a simple example of my problem:

table.html

(the < head > part is not obligatory - everything is solved in ui.R)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test table </title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable();
  } );
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></body></html>
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$script(src="aa.js"),
    tags$script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"),
    tags$script(src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"),
    tags$link(rel = 'stylesheet', type = 'text/css', href = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css")
  ),


  titlePanel("Testing datatable HTML"),

  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("inc")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("table.html"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})
})
```

aa.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Comment: You may be interested in this package: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend! This package solves everything for me!

Answer (score 0):

Replaces DataTable by dataTable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```